# How best to implement save() and setDirty() for my Java beans model?

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I have a Java model which is effectively a tree of Java beans. Different areas of my application can change different beans of the model. When finished, I want to save the model, which should be able to work out which beans have actually changed, and call there

I know I can implement save(), isDirty() and setDirty() methods in all the beans, and have the setter check whether there is a change and call setDirty(). But ideally I don't want to have to programmicatically do this for each setter. I want to just be able to add new properties to the beans with no additional coding.

I'm also aware of PropertyChangeListeners, but again I would have to programmatically fire a change in each setter.

Can anyone recommend a pattern/aspect/annotation that I might be able to use to make my life easier? I don't think what I'm trying to achieve is everything new or groundbreaking so hoping there's something out there I can use.

Note that I'm coding in basic Java, so no fancy frameworks to fall back on (expect Spring for bean management - outside of my model).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let profane ask a question. What if your bean is just a container of some subobject. You call mybean.someContainedObject.setValue(v). Please note that setXXX was applied from contained object, which is unmanaged and is saved only when mybean is dirty. This means that your bean was updated yet no of its setXXX methods called. Is it what you want?